# Is there an expression for directing your opinion to someone but you use someone else's name?

Tags: expressions

Imagine there are 3 people A, B, and C. A and B are talking, A says to B that person C thinks he is arrogant. But actually, that's what person A is thinking. He just uses person C to avoid possible side effects or to make his opinion more valuable. The important thing is that person A does not have bad intention. Is there an expression in English that would explain what person A is doing?

Comment: Given the example, I can't see how "person A does not have bad intention" could work. Person A is being dishonest about their own opinion and potentially creating strife between B & C at the same time.

Comment: @KillingTime It that example yes. But what if person A wants to share an opinion on the subject of physics. His opinion is right. But he is not known as a good physicist so he says person C said it because person A wants to give value to his opinion. Otherwise, it would not have such value.